# How to store hierarchical information into a database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, hierarchical-data, database-schema

I have the following information that should be retrieved by using several dependent select fields on a web form:

Users will be able to add new categories.

```
Food
 - Fruits
   - Tropical
      - Pineapples
          - Pineapples - Brazil
          - Pineapples - Hawaii
      - Coconuts
   - Continental
      - Orange
 - Fish

....
```

This data should come from a database.

I realize that creating a table for each category here presented is not a good schema perhaps, so I would to ask, if is there any standard way to deal with this?

I'm also aware of this schema example:
[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Is there any other (perhaps more intuitive way) to store this type of information ?

Comment: How much easier than a parent_id shall it be?

Comment: In my view, in a perfect world, we'd all be using XML databases, which can store relational data or hierarchical data in a more natural form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided describes the two standard ways for storing this type of information:

- Adjacency List
- Nested Sets

Comment: Thanks. So those are the ways to go hm... ?

Comment: Yeah. I generally use nested sets for larger sets of hierarchical data and Adjacency Lists for smaller sets.  The article you linked to describes the advantages of the different approaches.

Comment: @MEM - your question says users will be able to add categories.  I think that ought to rule out Nested Sets, as the mechanism for shuffling the LFT and RGT values (as shown in the article) is quite quite horrible.  BTW, handling hierarchical data in pure SQL is one area where Oracle has lots to offer.  See this answer for an overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547349/rails-model-with-foreign-key-to-itself/5547450#5547450

Answer (score 2):

One issue your question didn't raise is whether all fruits have the same attributes or not.

If all fruits have the same attributes, then the answer that tells you to look at the link you provided and read about  adjacency lists and nested sets is correct.

If new fruits can have new attributes,  then a user that can add a new fruit can also add a new attribute.  This can turn into a mess, real easily.  If two users invent the same attribute, but give it a different name, that might be a problem.  If two users invent different attributes, but give them the same name, that's another problem.

You might just as well say that, conceptually, each user has their own database, and **no meaningful queries can be made that combine data from different users**.  Problem is, the mission of the database almost always includes, sooner or later, bringing together all the data from the different users.

That's where you face a nearly impossible data management issue.

Comment: Indeed. The all hard part here is exactly that. I will need to cross information, and compare... I have no clue how to achieve that here.

Answer (score 1):

Kawu gave you the answer.... a recursive relation (the table will be be related to itself) aka *Pig's Ear* relation.

You example shows a parent with several children, but you didn't say if an item can belong to more that one parent.  Can an orange be in 'Tropical' and in 'Citrus'?

Each row has an `id` and a `parent_id` with the `parent_id` pointing to the `id` of another row.

```
id=1 name='Fruits' parent_id=0
id=2 name='Citrus' parent_id=1
id=3 name='Bitter Lemon' parent_id=2
id=4 name='Pink Grapefruit' parent_id=2
```

Here are some examples of schemas using this type of relation to provide unlimited parent-child relations:

- [Data model for product categories](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/product_categories/index.htm)
- [Data model for organizations and people](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/organisations_and_people/index.htm)

Comment: perhaps that will arrive.Let's say user A as a product Orange A, and user B as a product Orange B. One will store their orange inside "Citrus", the other will be inside "Tropical" - I don't mind, since both make sense. So, we will allow our users to find that product (orange), either by navigating to Citrus or Tropical, if they go to **Citrus** they will find **USER A orange**, if they go trough **Tropical** they will find **USER B Orange** but they will find and orange. It's not perfect... but if the point is to find and store an orange, even if redundancy, I can leave with that.

Comment: Then the above would work... but it still does not address the case where User A explicitly wants to store Orange A under more than one category.